# How can I make a list of websites in my book?

Tags: lists, glossaries, acronyms

I want to make a list of websites in the last pages of my book. Something like the list bellow:

```
List of websites:
-----------------------------------------------
website01 ....................... description01
website02 ....................... description02
website03 ....................... description03
website04 ....................... description04
website05 ....................... description05
```

I have read the acro and glossaries packages but I could not make a MWE. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{website01}{name=website01,description=description01}
\newglossaryentry{website02}{name=website02,description=description02}
\newglossaryentry{website03}{name=website03,description=description03}
\newglossaryentry{website04}{name=website04,description=description04}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

\gls{website01}, \gls{website02}, \gls{website03}, \gls{website04}.

\printglossary[title=List of Websites,style=listdotted]

\end{document}
```

To build the document use: pdflatex, makeglossaries, pdflatex.

The resulting glossary looks like:

[image: Image of glossary]

Second possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{website01}{name=website01,description=description01}
\newglossaryentry{website02}{name=website02,description=description02}
\newglossaryentry{website03}{name=website03,description=description03}
\newglossaryentry{website04}{name=website04,description=description04}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

\gls{website01}, \gls{website02}, \gls{website03}, \gls{website04}.

\printnoidxglossary[title=List of Websites,style=listdotted]

\end{document}
```

To build the document run (pdf)latex twice. The result is the same as before.

If you want hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{website01}{name={\url{website01}},description=description01}
\newglossaryentry{website02}{name={\url{website02}},description=description02}
\newglossaryentry{website03}{name={\url{website03}},description=description03}
\newglossaryentry{website04}{name={\url{website04}},description=description04}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

\gls{website01}, \gls{website02}, \gls{website03}, \gls{website04}.

\printnoidxglossary[title=List of Websites,style=listdotted,sort=def]

\end{document}
```

This orders the list according to definition. If you want to sort according to usage replace `sort=def` with `sort=use`.

Comment: Does it matter if I don't use `\gls{` in my text?

Comment: Well, this is better than my 'solution'... I guess, it has something to do with the fact that Nicola is the author of `glossaries` ;-)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent No, just use `\glsaddall` as in Christian's answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Is there any way to import the websites and their descriptions from a cvs file?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Yes, you could use `datatool`, but I think you'd need to ask that as a follow-up question. If you're not using `\gls` in your document, then you don't really need to use `glossaries`.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and short way, without much configuration...

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{glossaries}


\newglossaryentry{website01}{name=website01,description={Blabla}}

\newglossaryentry{website02}{name=website02,description={Another Blabla}}


\makeglossaries



\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={List of websites}]
\end{document}
```

[image]